# Dropwizard/Jersey returns Java List as JSON without root node

Tags: java, jersey, dropwizard

I am using dropwizard which uses jersey & jackson for json. My issue is when I return a list it does not specify a root.

I have a POJO class:

```
public class Company { 
public String id; 
public String name; 
public String address; 
}
```

and my resource is set up thus:

```
@GET
@Path("/companies/all")
public List<Company> getAllCompanies(){
    ...
    return companies;
}
```

And I get the following response:

```
[{
"id": "01",
"name": "Yammer Corp",
"address": "1 Finite Loop"
},
{
"id": "02",
"name": "DropWizards Inc",
"address": "4 Magic Square, Olympus"
}]
```

While what I want is something like below:

```
{"Companies" : 
[{
"id": "01",
"name": "Yammer Corp",
"address": "1 Finite Loop"
},
{
"id": "02",
"name": "DropWizards Inc",
"address": "4 Magic Square, Olympus"
}
]}
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to have one more POJO wrapping that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create one more POJO wrapping the `List<Company>`

```
public class ApiResponse
{
   private List<Company> Companies;
   //Getter and Setter
   //Public Constructor
}
```

The Change required in your GET Method is:

```
@GET
@Path("/companies/all")
public ApiResponse getAllCompanies(){
    //Set your ApiResponse Object with the companies List.
    ApiResponse apiResponse = new ApiResponse(companies);
    return apiResponse;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Srinivas, I followed you implemetation and it worked! I modified it a bit: `public class JSONListWrapper {
    public List<?> itemlist;
    public JSONListWrapper(List<?> itemlist) {
        this.itemlist = itemlist;
    }
}`

Comment: I tend to use a POJO called `ApiResponse` which has `status_code`, `status_message` and `data` which is an `Object` and acts a payload. Feels a lot neater than modifying ObjectMapper.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can customize using Jackson APIs. Here is one approach which allows you to set the root of the generated JSON using [ObjectWriter](http://fasterxml.github.com/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.1.1/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectWriter.html).

```
    @GET
    @Path("/companies/all")
    public Response getAllCompanies() throws JsonProcessingException {
        List<Company> companies = Lists.newArrayList();
        Company yc = new Company();
        yc.id = "01";
        yc.name = "Yammer Corp";
        yc.address = "1 Finite Loop";
        companies.add(yc);
        Company dw = new Company();
        dw.id = "02";
        dw.name = "DrowWizards Inc";
        dw.address = "4 Magic Square, Olympus";
        companies.add(dw);

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ObjectWriter writer = objectMapper.writer();
        String entity = writer.withRootName("Companies").writeValueAsString(companies);
        return Response.ok(entity).build();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at your code you are asking to return a list of companies:

```
public List<Company> getAllCompanies(){
```

If you want to return a JSON object with a Companies value then you need a suitable Java object which matches this.

```
public class MyListOfCompanies {
  List<Companies> companies;
}
```

And then you would ask your code to return that instead:

```
public MyListOfCompanies getAllCompanies(){
```

However, do consider if you really want to do this.  If you think about the situation of someone coding to your API, would they rather receive a list of companies (as they asked for and the API implies they will obtain), or an object that serves no purpose other than to contain the list of companies?

Finally, for good REST design the common way to obtain a list of all companies is just to use the path /companies, not /companies/all.

Comment: I agree with the REST Url /companies instead of /companies/all. However, I see a valid use case of "naming" each of the parameters in the JSON. I come across folks who send such stuff in Body and none of them are named. It is pretty difficult when JSON has multi-levels.

Comment: Bear in mind that as soon as you have multiple levels then everything other than the top level will be named.  You can see this in the output in your question.  Also, by definition your top level will *never* be named.  All you're doing with creating a container object is putting a new unnamed object at the top level.